# Duplicate size swatches on some product pages

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3.4, swatches

I've got something strange going on here and I can't pinpoint where the problem is.

On some of the products pages I am getting duplicate size swatches

[image]

What could be causing this issue? Could it be a misconfiguration of a product?

Answer (score 0):

This look to me as you are using the default Magento sample products. The sample won't have issue, meaning, you should check from your side.

You can start by checking the configuration, see if you set it twice? (I don't know if it's possible)

And then start looking for third-party theme/module that you recently installed. Turn them off one by one.

If you know about coding, you can open console window to see if there's any error, or take a look at the code, where it renders to see if's something strange in there

Comment: In the screenshot I'm just showing the default magento sample products but on the site with real products, this is the behaviour for some products. I've checked the product catalogue in admin and it look fine. I did check the console and can see when that part is rendered which is called once so during render it's creating it twice